# Raid controller serial number

Tags: command-line, raid

Is there a way I can pull various information from my RAID controller using a command?

Specifically, I am interested in (at least) the following:

- Raid controller serial number
- Raid controller type of cache memory (Battery Backed/ Flash)
- Raid controller cache memory model/part number
- Raid controller cache memory serial number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your hardware raid controller, but more likely then not you can find this information.

You first need to identify your raid card

```
lspci -vv | grep -i raid
```

This will show the hardware.

For Debian/ Ubuntu systems IMO this is the next page you should go to

https://wiki.debian.org/LinuxRaidForAdmins

More likely then not you will need to download and install vendor specific software and that page will tell you what to download and where to obtain and install the software.

Then you need to read the man page or find a tutorial on the tool. My only experience is with megaraid and to be honest the documentation was not great and took a while for me to work through. At the end of the day you may need to read the man page.

Here is a referance for what megaraid will do - https://hwraid.le-vert.net/wiki/LSIMegaRAIDSAS

If you need more specific information you need to identify your hardware or at least post the output of `lspci -vv | grep -i raid`

See also this discussion about hardware / software RAID - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139271/how-to-get-details-of-raid-devices-both-soft-and-hard